# Origine di: “La rava e la fava”

Tags: phrase-origin

Il modo di dire “la rava e la fava” è molto comune e come precisato sotto si usa in riferimento a spiegazioni fin troppo dettagliate. L’origine citata dal dizionario Hoepli mi sembra un po’ “fantasiosa”; mi chiedo se qualcuno abbia maggiori informazioni a riguardo.

***[dalla rava alla fava](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/F/fava.shtml)*** (pop):

> Dettagliatamente, esaurientemente, con grande dovizia di particolari.
>
> - Si può supporre derivi dall'immagine di una pianticella descritta in ogni sua parte, dalla radice al frutto; da qui l'idea di partire dalle cose più importanti per arrivare alle minuzie, senza trascurare nemmeno le piccolezze. Per arrivare alla rima con fava si sarebbe trasformata in rava la voce dialettale “rama”, che in molte località sta per “rami”, quindi frasche e fogliame.

Comment: Per curiosità, molto comune dove? Io non l'avevo mai sentito... (+1 in ogni caso, domanda interessante :))

Comment: Espressione usata in Piemonte e Lombardia, usata anche da Enzo Jannacci nella canzone [I soliti accordi](https://wikitesti.com/i_soliti_accordi/)

Comment: "Rava" assomiglia di più a "rapa". Qui ho trovato una spiegazione leggermente diversa: http://www.conexion-to.it/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=513:il-politically-correct-questo-sconosciuto&catid=39:societa

Comment: @DenisNardin A Milano si dice abitualmente

Comment: Personalmente non uso questa espressione, ma molte volte qualcuno mi ha detto "non sto a dirti la rava e la fava" mentre mi descriveva qualche fatto. Ho sempre pensato che significasse non sto a dirti la differenza tra una rapa e una fava, cosa che già dovresti conoscere, ovvero non mi dilungo in dettagli inutili, e passo subito al nocciolo della questione. Non so però se questa sia la vera origine.

Comment: Sono piemontese ed in Piemonte l'espressione è usatissima. Esistono anche moltissimi ristoranti e trattorie in P. & Lombardia, che fanno pensare ad una connessione `alimentare`. Com'è già stato detto `rava` è piemontese per rapa. L'espressione è normalmente usata come "miscuglio esaustivo" di molti elementi. "Pare abbia a che fare con una ricetta di minestrone contadino dove si metteva di tutto". Vedi commenti http://fabioletterario.blog.kataweb.it/il_mio_weblog/2006/06/12/la-rava-e-la-fava/.

Comment: @Enzo Non ho capito cosa intendi dire. il fatto che ci siano molti ristoranti nel Nord-Ovest (ma è poi vero? Sono più che nel resto d'Italia? Non mi è mai sembrato...) suggerirebbe che l'espressione viene da una ricetta? Per che motivo?

Answer (score 6):

Cito testualmente da [*Il mare in un imbuto: dove va la lingua italiana*](http://www.einaudi.it/libri/libro/gian-luigi-beccaria/il-mare-in-un-imbuto/978880620044) di   Gian Luigi Beccaria (linguista e critico letterario):

> ...raccontare **la rava e la fava** (*all'origine l'espressione era un richiamo tipico dei fruttivendoli ambulanti di una volta, che insieme a frutta, verdura, vendevano anche «rape e fave»*), vale a dire 'raccontare di tutto, ogni cosa nei dettagli', 'una storia senza fine'. Una volta pronunciato rava, la fava nasce come una eco del significante che precede, e l'insieme del sintagma nel complesso sembrerebbe voler abbracciare, racchiudere specularmente una totalità, voler raccontare appunto 'di tutto'.

Answer (score -1):

La rava deriva da *ravanare* che si riferisce ad un metodo complesso di preparazione del terreno per alcune colture quindi il detto la rava e la fava indica un discorso che parte da una base complessa e si sviluppa addentrandosi minuziosamente nei particolari

Comment: Potresti aggiungere qualche riferimento riguardante quello che sostieni?