# Etimologia di "Ravenna" e altri toponomi italiani

Tags: etymology, proper-nouns

Una discussione a proposito di [questo post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/8704/origine-di-la-rava-e-la-fava) ha suggerito che l'origine del nome "Ravenna" e di altri toponomi italiani potrebbe avere qualcosa a che vedere con "rava". Mi è sembrato un fatto interessante. Qualcuno di voi ne saprebbe spiegare qualcosa?

Comment: https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etimologia_dei_toponimi_italiani_capoluogo_di_provincia#R

Comment: @egreg: "Prelativo" sarebbe un refuso per "prelatino"?

Comment: Suppongo di sì. Dubito comunque che questo *rava* sia collegato con “rava e fava”.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uno studio di Giacomo Devoto, uno dei massimi esperti internazionali di linguistica indo-europea, afferma che il nome della città di Ravenna deriva dal prelatino *rava che significa "frana" e che deriva da una lingua pre-indoeuropea che utilizzava la base *rav- per designare l'idea di 'scorrere dell'acqua'.

Ecco alcuni toponimi italiani che hanno questa radice:

- La città di Ravenna, nell'omonima provincia e la frazione di Ravalle, in provincia di Ferrara, entrambe dell'Emilia-Romagna.
- La Comune di Raveo, in provincia di Udine, nella regione Friuli-Venezia Giulia.
- La frazione di Rava del Comune di Valtorta, in provincia di Bergamo, nella regione Lombardia.
- Il torrente Rava, un affluente del fiume San Bartolomeo di Venafro, in provincia di Isernia, della regione Molise.
- Val di Rabbi e Laghi di Rava, Cima di Rava e Ravetta, a Bieno, entrambi in provincia di Trento, in Trentino-Alto Adige
- Il torrente Rabaù, Raboeu o Fontanile di Tradate. Nato nella Cascina Lovaneda, nella città di Monello nel comune di Binago, Lombardia.

Fonti: DEVOTO G., *Due basi toponomastiche: Rava e Noukria*, Venezia: Coi tipi di Carlo Ferrari, 1934, 14 p. Soggetti: Rava -toponimo-, Noukria -toponimo-, Ravenna -toponimo-. 
DEVOTO G., *Nomi locali mediterranei: rava "frana" e Ravenna*, In Idem, *Scritti minori*, 3 voll. Firenze, 1958 - 1972: pp 54-61 del secondo volume.

Comment: Mi sembra opportuno menzionare che nel [tuo blog](http://famiglia-rabai.blogspot.com/p/etimologia-del-apellido-rabai-ravai-o.html?m=1) hai raccolto queste e altre informazioni interessanti al riguardo.

Comment: Per esempio, nel tuo blog ho trovato interessante sapere che il [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI15/00570.jpg) (il cosiddetto Battaglia) menziona che anche il vocabolo "ravaneto" potrebbe avere la stessa origine.

Comment: Per curiosità, @Ravai: in un tuo commento precedente spiegavi che la tua origine era ligure, ma che i tuoi antenati si erano racati a Siviglia nel XVII secolo provenienti da da Casanova Lerrone, a Savona, in Liguria. Non ho capito se tu sei nato in Liguria oppure in Siviglia.

Comment: Il mio ottavo nonno, Giovanni Battista Rabai, nacque nel 1647 a Casanova Lerrone, Albenga, nella Repubblica di Genova.  Con dieci anni arriva a Siviglia con la sua famiglia.  Ed è in questa città di Siviglia che nascono generazione dopo generazione fino a quando non mi raggiungono.  Durante questi quasi quattro secoli il cognome Rabai subisce dei cambiamenti.  Oggi puoi trovare a Siviglia il cognome Rabai come Rabáez (il mio) e come Rabay.

Comment: Il mio sospetto è che in origine il mio cognome fosse Rava, perché vivevo in una zona di montagna dove ci sono torrenti e scogliere.  Immagino da lì abbia preso il suo cognome e alla fine potrebbe cambiare in Rabai.  Il cognome Rava è il più diffuso in Italia tra le diverse opzioni disponibili (Rava, Ravaglioli, Rabai, Ravai, Ravasi e altri)

Comment: Interessante, @Ravai. Quindi, tu sei nato a Siviglia?

Comment: Sì, sono nato a Siviglia nel 1974. 

YDNA Paterno: R1b-U152 + L2 + BY4245 + BY3485 + BY3478 +, Giovanni Domenicus Rabai, n.  1609, Savona, Italia

Manuel David Rabaez 1974, Manuel Rabaez 1948, Manuel Rabaez 1912, Antonio Rabay 1868, Antonio Rabay 1833, Manuel Rabay 1791, Manuel Rabay 1764, Pedro Rabai 1727, Pedro Joseph Rabai 1691, Giovanni Battista Rabai 1647, Jo.  Domenicus Rabai 1609, Pietrus Rabai (lavori in corso ...)