# Quale verbo usare nella frase "Ho cercato di .......... la tua proposta"

Tags: verbs, word-choice

In un commento a [questo post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/8704/origine-di-la-rava-e-la-fava), che adesso è cancellato, ho scritto la frase

> Ho cercato di ***eseguire***  la tua proposta

ma ho avuto il dubbio se "eseguire" fosse il verbo più adatto. Magari è troppo formale? Quale verbo posso usare? Ho cercato su Google frasi simili a questa, ma non sono riuscita a trovarle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ecco alcune frasi che puoi usare:

- Ho cercato di fare quello che hai proposto.
- Ho cercato di seguire la tua proposta.
- Ho cercato di mettere in pratica la tua proposta.
- Ho cercato di mettere in atto la tua proposta (più  formale).

Comment: Benvenuta/o su Italian.SE e grazie della risposta!

Comment: Anche “mettere in pratica”, “mettere in atto” (più formale).

Comment: @DaG: Quindi, potrei dire "Ho cercato di mettere in pratica la tua proposta" e anche sostituire "pratica" con "atto" (ma è più formale). Possiamo aggiungerlo a questa risposta?

Comment: @DaG: Posso aggiungerlo io stessa?

Comment: Certo, @Charo, fai pure.